# gridview textboxes column sum using jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview

I have a gridview having text boxes in template fields and buttons in footer, on footer button click i want to calculate the total of template column's having textboxes but i am not able to get textboxe's value.i am using following code in my aspx page

```js
 function ValidateTotalPercentage(CellNo) 
    {


        var ages = 0;
        var weights = 0;
        var benchpresses = 0;

        //reference the rows you want to add
        //this will not include the header row
        var rows = $("#<%=grdMaterialPercentage.ClientID%> tr:gt(0)");
        rows.children("td:nth-child(" + CellNo + ")").each(function () {
            //each time we add the cell to the total

        var str= $(this).html();

        alert(str.toString().indexOf("value"));
        });

        alert(ages);

        return false;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function ValidateTotalPercentage(CellNo) {

    var ages = 0;
    var weights = 0;
    var benchpresses = 0;

    //reference the rows you want to add
    //this will not include the header row
    var rows = $("#<%=grdMaterialPercentage.ClientID%> tr:gt(0)").not("tr:last");
    rows.children("td:nth-child(" + CellNo + ")").each(function () {
        //each time we add the cell to the total

        //If the text field accepts decimal values then use parseFloat to convert the number
        ages = ages + parseInt($(this).find("input").val());

        //alert(str.toString().indexOf("value"));
    });

    alert(ages);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ShankarSangoli now i am able to fetch text boxes value but also i want to exclude footer it is adding footer value as NAN

Comment: - i have used edited code but it is giving ages 0 even not going in loop.

rows.length is 0

Comment: Do you have any class for footer row?

Comment: i have this css class for footer button

.button
{
    background: url(../images/button.jpg) repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 23px;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}